# how to get the deb package full path in the pre-install script

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu, deb

I have built a deb package with the pre-install script .
I want to auto bakup the deb package after installed.
So I want to get the full path of the package in the pre/post-install script. are there any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Maintainer scripts (`preinst`, `postinst` etc.) are given a number of pieces of information, but that doesn’t include the full path of the package file they were installed from — in particular, because *when* they run, the package file may no longer exist.

See [the “Internal environment” section of `man dpkg`](https://manpages.debian.org/dpkg/dpkg.1#Internal_environment) for details of the information available, on top of the arguments given to the scripts. To understand the various circumstances in which a maintainer script can be invoked, see [the maintainer scripts flowcharts appendix in Debian Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-flowcharts.html); note in particular that even old `preinst` and `postinst` scripts can be called, they aren’t only useful when installing the package containing them.

You might be able to do what you’re after by using `dpkg` hooks, specifically a `post-invoke` hook triggered by `install`.

Answer (score 1):

The author of a `deb` file should not have the right to decide how a user archives their packages.  When you `dpkg -i mypkg.deb`, `mypkg.deb` is not deleted.  You, as a user, can choose whether to archive that package yourself.

If you install packages via `apt`, packages are automatically archived in `/var/cache/apt/archives` by apt.  A user can disable this in `apt.conf`.  That control is global for all packages, not on a per-package-basis.

---

The name of the `deb` package it was extracted from is not passed as an argument to `preinst`.  Therefore, you cannot simply:

```
cp "$2" /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

Also, the working directory of `preinst` is `/`.  Therefore, even if you assumed that a user did not rename the package, you still cannot do this:

```
cp mypkg.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

---

I think the closest thing you can do is to use the `dpkg-repack` tool. This is not part of the standard tools and will need to be installed via `apt install dpkg-repack`.  It should therefore be a dependency of your package if you use it.

`man dpkg-repack` says:

> `dpkg-repack` creates a .deb file out of a Debian package that has already been installed on your system.  If any changes have been made to the package while it was unpacked (e.g.  conffiles files in `/etc` modified), the new package will inherit the changes.  (There are exceptions to this, including changes to configuration files that are not conffiles, including those managed by `ucf(1)`.)

Since this only works on an installed package, you'd need to move this from `preinst` to the end of `postinst`.

```
dpkg-repack mypkg
mv mypkg_1.0-1_all.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

Note that I would label this as 'volatile' at best.  I wouldn't recommend doing this, unless this package is not meant to be published.  If it's just your own personal settings that you would like to be able to restore and apply to your next machine, and you just want a easy way to archive your package, then it's probably fine.  But consider that a simple `echo "Don't forget to archive me!"` might work just as well.

---

A better alternative to the idea above would be to create a local `apt` repository.  Put this package in that repository, add the local repository to your `sources.list`, then `apt install mypkg` instead of `dpkg -i mypkg.deb`.  Then `apt` will use your global policy to determine how to archive `mypkg.deb`.

This has the added benefit of not forcing an archive of the package on any other users you may share this with.

There are a few ways to create a local `apt` repository:

- `dpkg-scanpackages`: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal
- `reprepro`: A little more complicated, but it's really good if you are managing a shared repository, especially if you include sources and need to sign things with a repository signature.

Comment: sorry, I just want to get the full path of  the current installing deb package( eg: /home/username/abc.deb ) in the pre/post-inst script. But It looks like there is no solution about this.

Comment: Correct.  That isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of getting down-voted, this can be done.  If you obtain the information of the parent process from the `preinst` script that will allow you to obtain the path to the package.  You need two pieces of information:

1. the working directory of the parent process
2. the last argument of the parent process (internally dpkg/apt calls dpkg-deb and the last argument after all the options is the full package name)

In practice, this looks like:

```
CALLING_DIR=$(realpath /proc/$(ps -o ppid:1= $$)/cwd)
DEBIAN_PKG=$(cd "${CALLING_DIR}"; realpath $(xargs -0 -n 1 < /proc/$(ps -o ppid:1= $$)/cmdline | tail -n 1))
echo "${DEBIAN_PKG}"
```

As noted by other answers, it is *highly unusual* to need this information.  The only reason I can think of to do this (what I'm playing with at the moment) is if your package generates redistributables that need to contain the package itself.  Other than that, it would be better to install a hook.